# How to obtain original size of image viewed in Windows.Forms PictureBox.Image

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to know [size of a image in a `PictureBox`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23659647/how-to-get-displayed-image-dimensions-of-an-image-scaled-to-fit-a-picturebox), but cannot to access the [`Image`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image?view=netcore-3.1) property, because it's nothing.

```vb
    Dim PiBox1 As New PictureBox
    With PiBox1
        .ImageLocation = "image.png"
        .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
        .Dock = DockStyle.fill
        If .Image Is Nothing Then MsgBox("Image = Nothing")
    End With
```

`PictureBox.Size`, `PictureBox.ClientSize` return dimensions of the control, not the image inside...

Comment: I expect the ImageLocation will start loading the image asynchronously, use `LoadCompleted` event to query the `.Image` property. Or synchronously load the image yourself using `.Image = Image.FromFile("image.png")` instead of using `.ImageLocation = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are other options, to change the code as little as possible, just add a call to the `Load` method after setting the `ImageLocation` property. That will force the `Image` to be loaded synchronously.

That said, you really ought to be setting the `Dock` and `SizeMode` properties first. Why would you load an `Image` first and then change the size afterwards? Do all the configuration first, then load the `Image` as the last step. This is akin to setting the `DataSource` last when data-binding.